# In the Lost Mine of Phandelver adventure, when does the Flameskull attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, attack, lost-mine-of-phandelver

Note: I'm French, and while I'm quite fluent in English, sometimes I get stumped by a sentence.

> On p. 46, under [room 12 ("Smelter Cavern")](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/lmop/wave-echo-cave#12SmelterCavern), it says that the flameskull's orders are to prevent anyone from passing through the room he defends.

Does that mean that the flameskull only attacks if you try to cross the room?

If someone takes a couple steps in then goes backwards into the same corridor they came in because of the zombies, would that trigger the flameskull or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The flame skull has its orders. It is also intelligent so it has discretion as to how it carries them out. That is, the DM decides what it does and when it does it.

As an aside, the orders do not *require* an attack, just *prevention*.

Comment: Thou Shall Not Pass

Comment: I would posit that given its alignment that attack is more likely than a gentle nudge the other way.

Comment: @Slagmoth posit away

Comment: ..well now I'm imagining the flameskull as Randal from *Clerks*.  "Aw, man, don't go in th-- don't go that way!  C'mon--  Geeeeez, I wasn't even supposed to be here today..."